# Dropzone doesn't upload files and has positioning problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dropzone.js

1. Dropzone only shows at the end of the form (initially I tried putting it above the summernote) so, the submit button showed only above it. For this reason, I tried putting it outside the form and I'm not sure it works.
2. I can't include Dropzone in any other div, so, for example, I can't put a border around it.
3. It looks like it doesn't upload any files (because the following code return only a blank page with "*1*" written on it - from the *upload.php* code).
4. Dropzone doesn't how the *RemoveImage* link

I used Dropzone because I don't think Summernote can upload other files like pdf, word.

*mainpage.php* :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="dropzone.js"></script>

    <!-- Summernote css -->
    <link href="../plugins/summernote/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Select2 -->
    <link href="../plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Jquery filer css -->
    <link href="../plugins/jquery.filer/css/jquery.filer.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../plugins/jquery.filer/css/themes/jquery.filer-dragdropbox-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- App css -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/components.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/switchery/switchery.min.css">
    <script src="assets/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Start content -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="page-title-box">
                            <h3>Postare raspuns</h3>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                        <div class="p-6">
                            <div class="">
                                <form id="myAwesomeDropzone" class="dropzone" action="upload.php" method="POST" style="border:none" novalidate>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                            <div class="card-box">
                                                <h4 class="m-b-30 m-t-0 header-title"><b>Textul postarii</b></h4>
                                                <textarea class="summernote" name="postdescription" id="postdescription" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <h4 class="m-b-30 m-t-0 header-title"><b>Ataseaza fisiere</b></h4>
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="fallback">
                                            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                                <br>
                                <input type="submit" name="pos" id="pos" value="Postare" class="btn btn-success btn-block" form="myAwesomeDropzone" />
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <div class="btn btn-info btn-block">
                                    <a href="read_topic.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" class="btn btn-block" style="color:white">Inapoi la subiect</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end p-20 -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end col -->
                </div>
                <!-- end row -->

            </div>
            <!-- container -->

        </div>
        <!-- content -->

    </div>
    <script>
        var resizefunc = [];
    </script>

    <!-- jQuery  -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/detect.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/waves.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/switchery/switchery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/jquery.filer/js/jquery.filer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/pages/jquery.blog-add.init.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.core.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.app.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.summernote').summernote({
                height: 240,
                minHeight: null,
                maxHeight: null,
                focus: false,
                toolbar: [
                    ['style', ['style']],
                    ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                    ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                    ['color', ['color']],
                    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                    ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
                ],
                popover: {
                    air: []
                }
            });
            $(".select2").select2();

            $(".select2-limiting").select2({
                maximumSelectionLength: 2
            });

            Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {

                autoProcessQueue: false,
                url: upload.php,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                parallelUploads: 20,
                maxFiles: 20,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                // Dropzone settings
                init: function() {
                    var myDropzone = this;
                    this.element.querySelector("#pos").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        myDropzone.processQueue();
                    });
                    this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
                       //Add additional data to the upload
                       formData.append("postdescription", jQuery("postdescription").val());
                   });
                   this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                        console.log('dfd');
                   });
                }

            }
        });

    </script>

    <script src="../plugins/switchery/switchery.min.js"></script>

    <!--Summernote js-->
    <script src="../plugins/summernote/summernote.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

*upload.php* :

```html
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key=>$val){
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
    // get file extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // get filename without extension
    $filenamewithoutextension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    if (!file_exists(getcwd(). '/uploads')) {
        mkdir(getcwd(). '/uploads', 0777);
    }
 
    $filename_to_store = $filenamewithoutextension. '_' .uniqid(). '.' .$ext;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], getcwd(). '/uploads/'.$filename_to_store);
}
echo "File(s) uploaded successfully";
}
else
{
echo "1";
}
?>
```

For question 3:
I tried this to see if *upload.php* really doesn't get any files, so I tried displaying an alert if the Dropzone Queue doesn't exist. But, when I click the submit button, it takes me to *upload.php* without displaying any alert.

```js
if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) {
                        alert("yes");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("error")
                    }
```